# ASP .Net Core MVC upload image to SQLite

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to upload an image file and add it to SQLite. I'm new to ASP .Net Core MVC and i'm following the tutorials from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-mac/?view=aspnetcore-2.0. 
I have added an input field to upload files in the View. However, I'm not sure how to go ahead with the Controller and Model. Tried searching everywhere. 
One approach is to convert the image to byte. I'm not sure how can I do that in my case. 
Any help appreciated :)

**Model:**

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    // use only letters (white space, numbers and special characters are not allowed). 
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$")]
    [StringLength(5)]
    [Required]
    public string Rating { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]    
      [Display(Name = "Upload File")]    
     // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose file to upload.")]    
    public string Poster { get; set; }   
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price,Rating,Poster")] Movie movie)
            {
                if (id != movie.ID)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _context.Update(movie);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                    {
                        if (!MovieExists(movie.ID))
                        {
                            return NotFound();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                return View(movie);
            }
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Genre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Rating" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Rating" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Rating" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Poster" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" asp-for="Poster" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Poster" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen your code but for me what i do on button click convert image to base64 using JavaScript like

```
var dataURL;
$("#uploadFileID").change(function() {
    var fileInput = $("#uploadFileID");
        var file = document.querySelector('#uploadFileID').files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (f) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            });
        }
  });
```

then send it to method using ajax post and save it to Database

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to upload file https://github.com/Sagardip/studentapp

```
public string Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        var uploadDirecotroy = "uploads/";
        var uploadPath = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, uploadDirecotroy);

        if (!Directory.Exists(uploadPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);

        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName);

        using (var strem = File.Create(filePath))
        {
            file.CopyTo(strem);
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```